# how to add controls to a panel with vertical space

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to add controls into my panel with vertical spacing?

This is my code for now:

```
 Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

    Dim pic As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
    Dim lb As Label = New Label()
    Dim cells As Integer = MoviesDataSet.movies.Count
    ReDim mypb(cells)
    ReDim mylb(cells)
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    For Each movie As DataRow In MoviesDataSet.movies

        pic.ImageLocation = Application.StartupPath & "\" & movie("moviePhoto")
        pic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(x, y)
        pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        pic.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 5)
        mypb(k) = pic

        lb.Text = movie("movieName")
        lb.AutoSize = True
        lb.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 10)
        mylb(k) = lb

        k += 1

    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To MyPB.Count - 1 Step 1
        Panel1.Controls.Add(MyPB(i))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(MyLb(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

My panel width is about 180 and height is about 170. I did that if the content is higher than the panel height, there are scroll bars. The code is adding all of the controls on the same spot so I can only see the last PHOTO.

How do I do that there will be a Photo, then a Label and then another photo and so on

Thanks!

Comment: If you want automatic layout instead of setting the Location property yourself then you'll need FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the images you place in your Control to be vertically aligned rather than all in the same position you need to calculate a new position for the control before placing it in the control.

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To 10

    Dim picture As New PictureBox() With
    {
        .Size = New Size(100, 30),
        .Location = New Point(10, .Height + (i * 40)),
        .BackColor = Color.Red
    }

    Panel1.Controls.Add(picture)
Next
```

I obviously can't test your code but this kind of logic should suffice:

```
pic.Location = new Point(10, pic.Height + (k * 40)
```

Comment: Just to get the logic behind it, why do you use k*40?

lets say that all of the pictures are 150height, you are saying that the location of the first one will be 10,150 the second 10,190 the thid 10,230 and so on. That means that the picture is going to start at this position which is creating a huge gap between each of them, this formula doesn't seems to work >.< any other idea?

Comment: I chose 40 to suit my controls 100x30. You can adjust it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. Your controls are 30 height, so you just insert a 10 vertical spacing between each control. alright! thanks ;)!